# Capture square video like vine and instagram (Solution and Example)

Tags: android, video-capture, video-recording

I want to record square video like vine and instagram application. Normally android can not record square video (ratio 1:1). How way to capture square video like vine or instagram. Thank

Answer (score 3):

This is not a simple question that can be answered in one answer. There is no shortcut on this you will have to create the layout and crop it manually. I was doing this few years ago and it took a while before i have everything sorted out.
There might be some library that can be of any use, if not using the full library go through the code and see how things are done.

I can recommend you this one:

> https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1745

Comment: Should I use ffmpeg for record video and crop each frame to square video?

Comment: Yes i was using ffmpeg that was the only solution back than, not sure if there is a shortcut to that.

Comment: Ok , Do you have example for use ffmpeg to crop frame or example about it? Thank

Comment: I found some code snippet of that app i wrote long time ago,
http://pastebin.com/P5LNZkep
See if this is of any help if not will try to look for more.

Comment: Thankyou very much for help me. :))

Comment: I think https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord nearby my problem. He use ffmpeg for record video.

Comment: @WuttipongKhemphetjetsada Have you implemented it right? I've been using FFmpeg in one project recently to crop Videos in square can land you the code if you want.

Comment: hi @VictorPetrovski i need that code snippet to record video in Sqaure .. can you help me ?

Comment: @Nitin I don't have current code for recording videos in the square. Please look at Android Arsenal I hope you will find something useful there.

Comment: @VictorPetrovski thanks i got solution from one library